# Display lots of mysql records

Tags: mysql, select

If i had a mysql db with 7000 records in it and i had to display all 7000 on my webpage. Are there any tips and tricks to speed the process up (the browser practically crashes before showing all the records) i know i should query it to reduce the number of records selected but i actually need to display 7000...

Comment: Is the page generated on the server? Do you use Ajax and generate the DOM yourself? Is paging the results an option? Which language do you use to generate the web page if server side? Which browser is used if client-side?

Comment: PHP, Firefox (my preference), at the moment i'm just selecting all records and displaying them in a simple table on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on output buffering : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

```
<?php

ob_start(); 

// do work...

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

**EDIT**

The following php fetches 10K products and outputs them as a table with no problems in 0.014 seconds.

```
<?php

ob_start(); 

$conn = new Mysqli("localhost", "vldb_dbo", "pass", "vldb_db");

$startTime = microtime(true);

$result = $conn->query(sprintf("call list_products(%d)", 10000));

echo "<table border='1'>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 echo sprintf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $row["prod_id"], $row["name"]);
}

echo "</table>";

echo sprintf("<br/>Page generated in %s secs",number_format(microtime(true) - $startTime, 6, ".", ""));

$result->close();   
$conn->close();

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

**SQL Script**

```
drop procedure if exists list_products;
delimiter #

create procedure list_products
(
in p_prod_id int unsigned
)
begin
    select * from product where prod_id between 1 and p_prod_id;
end #

delimiter ;
```

Works fine with 50K records too except runtime dives - Page generated in 0.112902 secs

**EDIT2**

http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php

An excerpt from the above link:

> An alternate way of speeding the above
>   code would be to use output buffering.
>   This will accumulate the output string
>   internally, and send the output in one
>   shot at the end of the script. This
>   reduces networking overhead
>   substantially at the cost of more
>   memory and an increase in latency. In
>   some of my code consisting entirely of
>   echo statements, performance
>   improvements of 15% have been
>   observed.

Comment: so i would do my usual mysql_connect, query, array, etc within these tags?

Comment: this is showing my inexperience, but where in phpmyadmin to i stick the SQL script, in the "Run SQL" windows? Or somewhere else...

Comment: you probably want to replace my stored procedure call with your "select * from table where.."

Comment: I get this if i run the php page: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_paging.php on line 13

Comment: btw - can the down-voter pls comment next time so i know what your gripe is - tia

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing this in PHP (which I'm not familiar with) but this is generic to all languages.

Query 7000 records into a list first, then display all the list in a scripting page (e.g. php, jsp for java, etc.). Don't allow your php page to open the connection, read each item from the list and displaying them. The client (browser) might wait indefinitely and cause a **session timeout**

Comment: by a list, i'm assuming you dont mean a <ul><li> etc...why not allow php to open a connection? I thought PHP & Mysql went hand in hand!?

Comment: by list, I meant an array...I don't mean open the connection and do HTML/PHP scripting at the same time...first read all 7000 records into an array and then populate them in php.

Answer (score 0):

f00: if he displays the result in table and the browser will survive to display the data, they wont be displayed correcly anyways. As far as I know, the table wont render correctly (in firefox)...
I think that paging the table is the only possible solution...

Comment: I'm using the jQuery plugin Datatables to paginate the results (im aware this is client not server side)

Comment: i didnt think it was relevant to the php/mysql grabbing 7000 results...is it?